# How can I use the python debugger in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pdb, ipdb

I use the `%pdb` command, but when I enter commands such as `up or p` to in the toggled `ipdb`, I get `*** Oldest frame`instead of moving the arrows up and down like the regular debugger. How can I set the tracer to inspect all code in the notebook? Thanks for the help.